# How to change Navigation Item Selected programmatically

Tags: android, menu-items

When I created a new project I used **Navigation Drawer Activity** 
[app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVWk6.jpg)

Now each menu item when I click on it will open a fragment by calling a method name replacement.

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                replaceFragment(0);
                setTit = "Your State Info.";
                setTitle(setTit);
 } else if (id == R.id.nav_flashcards) {

            replaceFragment(1);
            setTit = "Flash Cards";
            setTitle(setTit);
```

in fragment 1 I have a RadioGroup when the checked change will open the fragmet depends on the radio checked.

```
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)getActivity().findViewById(i);

            if(radioButton.getTag()==1)
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragment(0);
           else if ((radioButton.getTag()==2))
             ((MainActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragment(2);
    }
```

The App work fine , but the issue is how can I change the Navigation Item Selected and also change the title for the action bar.

it's possible to use this way

```
 ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onNavigationItemSelected(menuitem);
```

but from the fragment how can I access the the items in the **menu>activity_main_drawer.xml** and pass it through menuitem

Answer (score 5):

This works for me..

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment you have to add `setOptionsMenu(true)`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: The fragment in  nav_flashcards will open a new fragment that representsl nav_home , the issue is how to move the selection item from nav_flashcards to nav_home

Answer (score 0):

question is not clear. 
whole point of `navigation drawer` with `fragments` is to access navigation and its main toolbar all over the fragments with a single main activity.(the blue color one in your image, you should be able to change this anytime when you load a fragment)

But you need to make the `frame`/parent view of the fragments blow the tool bar view(that's why normally it comes with two `XML`s, `activtyMain.xml` and `contentMain.xml`  where content main is included below the tool bar in `activityMain.XML`) so you create fragments view `match_parent` to this `contentMain.xml` ,you can see toolbar is accessible to the each and every fragment you add in that view because its in the main activity where fragment/s add.

so you have a main activity and inside that you have fragment/s frame. Doesn't matter what fragment you load you can still have the access to main toolbar.

*so once you check which item got clicked in `navigationDrawer` you load the fragment related to that right?. and there access the main toolbar of the `mainActivity` and do the changes that you need to display.That's it!*

```
 if (id == R.id.nav_whatever) {
 // access toolBar or any view in main activity and do the changes 
// call relevant  fragment  
 }
```

But you cannot access that `toolbar` or `mainActivity` views inside your Fragment class that you try to attempt.

**Edit :**

Keep a Boolean in a Constant class or something similar,
then when you click on your button on second fragment change the value .
Now let's say Boolean is true 
Then you click the navigation drawer again

```
    // keep the id as it is and use the Boolean to check where you needs to go
     if (id == R.id.nav_whatever) {
       if(boolianName){
         // boolianName is true go load second fragment
           }else{
             // load firstfragment
            }

         }
```

Comment: What I mean is in nav_flashcards fragment there is a radio button when I click on it will open a new fragment and will replace the current one with new one and that will be the nave_home through the code  ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onNavigationItemSelected , but when I open the menu the item selection still in the nav_flashcards , therefore I need a way to change the item selection through nav_flashcards  to nav_home

Comment: you mean you have a name in your navigation drawer item which has the name of 1st fragment. and you want to change it when you load the second fragment ?

Comment: The menu item  (R.id.nav_home) when click this menu  open fragment 0 , menu item id (R.id.nav_flahcard) when click this menu item open fragment 1 , now inside fragment 1 there is  radio button when I click this radio will open fragment 0  but  if  we open the menu item the selection on (R.id.nav_flahcard) therefore I need also to change the menu item selection to (R.id.nav_home) when I open the fragment 0 through the radio button

Answer (score 0):

If you use Navegation drawer, you can use this code, put it on onCreate method:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
```

Comment: You are using the same code that I published on Dec 3